# Why can I await a promise resolve execution, but not a promise reject one?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have been playing around with promises and I've found a curious behavior. Why is this promise awaited when I await the `resolve` call, but not when I await the `reject` call?

```js
(async () => {
    let resolve, reject;
    const promise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
        resolve = _resolve;
        reject = _reject;
    });
    promise.then(_ => console.log('Promise resolved'));
    await resolve(); // Instead of "resolve(); await promise;", which would be more natural
    console.log('Thread still running');
})()
```

```js
(async () => {
    let resolve, reject;
    const promise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
        resolve = _resolve;
        reject = _reject;
    });
    await reject(); // Instead of "reject(); await promise;", which would be more natural
    console.log('Thread still running');
})()
```

Comment: No. `await resolve()` will **not** await the promise. It's equivalent to `resolve(); await undefined;`. Same for the one with `reject`.

Comment: Try running the code in the chrome console though; in the first case`'Thread still running'` gets printed after `'Promise resolved'`

Comment: @RyanWilson, is there a better place where to post this offtopic questions?

Comment: @RyanWilson It should simply be closed as a "*problem that can no longer be reproduced*". The topic itself would be on-topic, if only the question was a better one.

Comment: Is the wording better now?

Comment: @Bergi Ok. Going to resubmit close vote as your suggested type once it allows me to.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Neither `resolve` nor `reject` return promises, so `await` doesn't do anything of note. The only difference is that when you `reject` you get an exception because you never catch it.

Comment: @Quentin So my question is: why in the second case I still get the console message `Thread still running`?

Comment: Sorry, of course I get it in the second case. What is not consistent is that the promise is being awaited in the first one

Comment: @CarlesCapellas — I said "Neither `resolve` nor `reject` return promises, so await doesn't do anything of note."

Comment: @CarlesCapellas "*the promise is being awaited in the first one*" - no it's not. What makes you think it is?

Comment: The messages order. When I run the code snippet I get `Promise resolved` first and then `Thread still running`. Isn't the same for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can only usefully `await` a promise.

`resolve` returns `undefined`. `reject` returns `undefined`. Neither of these is a promise so `await` has no practical effect.

```js
(async() => {
  let resolve, reject;
  const promise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve = _resolve;
    reject = _reject;
  });
  promise.then(_ => console.log('Promise 1 resolved'));
  const resolve_return_value = resolve();
  console.log({
    resolve_return_value
  });
  await resolve_return_value;
  console.log('Thread 1 still running');
})();

(async() => {
  let resolve, reject;
  const promise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve = _resolve;
    reject = _reject;
  });
  const reject_return_value = reject();
  console.log({
    reject_return_value
  });
  await reject_return_value;
  console.log('Thread 2 still running');
})();
```

When you pass a function to the `Promise` constructor it is given two arguments which are functions which allow you to resolve or reject *that* promise.

Don't confuse them with `Promise.reject()` and `Promise.resolve()` which return **new** promises that are immediately rejected or resolved.

Comment: Sorry for insisting but, removing the `await resolve_return_value;` line changes the outcome of the execution. I know that it doesn't make sense to await the `resolve` call, but it seems to modify the behaviour of the code

Comment: @CarlesCapellas — The `await` influences microtask resolution order. That's usually not significant.

Comment: Now we are talking :D Do you have any material reference from which I could learn more about this?